# Crystal oscillator error due to ppm

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, crystal, error, calculation

In this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15851/what-is-the-ppm-in-the-crystal-oscillator), the accepted answer states that there may be an error of 1 minute per month if the crystal ppm is 20ppm.

Can someone help me with the math of how the error of 1 minute is arrived?

Comment: (31x24x60x60) x 0.00002 = 54 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPM = parts per million.
$$20 ppm = \frac{20}{1000000}$$

If you want to find how long it takes for the error to reach 60 seconds (1 minute,) then you divide the 60 seconds by the ppm value.

$$T_{seconds} = \frac{60}{\frac{20}{1000000}}= 3000000 seconds$$

Converting 3000000 seconds to days gives 34 days.  That's a little over one month (31 days.)